# Appropriate way to ask for revision in Salary as the designation changes

Tags: salary, salary-review

I have been offered a higher position at the company I recently joined about 3 months ago. I have had a fair idea that I was being considered for the position for a while. I was asked if I'd be interested in taking up the role and I responded positively. At the same time, I was hoping the change in salary would be brought up but that was not the case. I would like to know what's an appropriate way to ask for a revision in Salary at this time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Does this new role come with an increase in salary?" seems an appropriate way to ask.

Comment: "just ask" is of course the right answer, but the best way to ask depends on who you are talking to. If OP works in dep. A and the new job is in dep B, the hiring manager in B may not know her current salary. In this case you can just ask for "job title" or "saralary band" " pay grade" or whatever classficiation your company uses to set compensation bands. If it's the same as your current one, it's unlikely to result in a significant raise

Comment: The best wording is "What is the salary?"

Comment: or "What is the salary of the XYZ role?"